# What happens to light when the light source is spinning rapidly

Tags: special-relativity, visible-light

In Einsteins analogy to demonstrate relativity, he asked that we envision two trains moving at different velocities, and then imagine a light shone from one train to the other.

Do we know what impact it would have if there was also a variance in the axial rotation of the light source (or the trains themselves).  Might it affect the speed of the light, or would it shift towards blue or red, depending on direction of rotation.

This is axial rotation.  spinning a flashlight like a rotisserie, not end over end like a baton twirler.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the rotation is perpendicular to the photon emission, it wouldn't affect the wavelength of the photon. However, if the tangential velocity were in the same direction as the emission of a photon then it would blue shift it. If they were opposite then it would be red shifted.